# SpringBoot not resolving devtools properties in tests

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, devtools

I'm using *spring-boot-devtools* with my SpringBoot application (2.2.8) to store secrets outside of my repository. This works for the running application, but integration tests fail with `Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'secret.key' in value "${secret.key}"`.

**SecretController.kt**

```kotlin
@RestController
class SecretController(
        @Value("\${secret.key}") private val secret: String
) {

    @GetMapping("/secret")
    fun secret(): String {
        return secret
    }
}
```

**.spring-boot-devtools.properties**

```
secret.key: secret-asdf
```

In an older application (SpringBoot 2.1) this works fine. I know they [changed the path with SpringBoot 2.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes), but [kept the old path as backwards compatibility](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html//using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-devtools-globalsettings) - I tried both without success. I also upgraded to 2.3.1, but this does not help either.

Any ideas on how to read properties in integration tests with SpringBoot >= 2.2?

Comment: seems like a bug in spring boot... spring boot 2.1 works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a bug but a conscious change, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5307

You shouldn't rely on devtools to configure your tests this way.

Comment: I know this is late, but says who?  I think it's a perfectly sane way to inject properties into integration tests as a developer working on a project.  What is the recommended workaround?  Just saying this is a bad idea doesn't mean it really is.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Says the Spring Boot team. You got your answer in the meantime via https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38098